# Brouwer's fixed point theorem and the one-point topology

Tags: general-topology, logic, category-theory, fixed-point-theorems

In the 2-dimensional case, Brouwer's fixed point theorem (BFPT) says that every continuous function $D^2\to D^2$ has a fixed point, where $D^2$ is the disk.

Now fix a particular topology: pick some point $x_0\in D^2$ and use it to define the one-point topology $\cal T_0$ on $D^2$: it includes all sets $A$ with $x_0\in A$, and the empty set. (This is indeed a topology, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology).

With respect to $\cal T_0$, a self map $D^2\to D^2$ is continuous if and only if it is constant or has $x_0$ as a fixed point. So, for every self map on $D^2$, continuity with respect to $\cal T_0$ means that a fixed point exists. Hence the BFPT is trivially true, by definition of $\cal T_0$.

In conclusion, there are topologies where BFPT is a theorem that requires proof, and there is a topology $\cal T_0$ where BFPT is true simply by definition.

> This gives $\cal T_0$ a special place among all possible topologies on $D^2$: it is the topology that makes BFPT trivial. Does such a situation or property have a name? Does it have a category theory interpretation (maybe like "universal property")?

> I feel there is a certain *equivalence* between BFPT and $\cal T_0$ here. They characterize each other in a certain way: $\cal T_0$ makes BFPT trivially true by definition, and BFPT links continuity and fixed points (like $\cal T_0$ does). Can this sense of equivalence be expressed rigorously?

*EDIT:* I want to thank you for the comments which were very helpful for me. I still seem to struggle with the question in my head, so I edited my question with the intention to make it more precise.

Comment: This might not be the answer you are looking for, but as you have pointed out, changing topologies can cause a lot of different things to happen. It doesn't make sense to say BPFT is a theorem about fixed points OR about topologies, those aren't mutually exclusive. It's just the statement that when you have a self map of a space homeomorphic (this fixes the topology on the space) to $D^n$, then it has a fixed point (here's the fixed point).

Comment: I'd say it's a theorem about continuous functions on *topological spaces*.

Comment: Some people study what kinds of spaces satisfy the Brouwer theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property . Khamsi and Kirk's "An Introduction to Metric Spaces and Fixed Point Theory" has a lot of related content.

Comment: @Idlewild Thanks a lot! I will follow your link and study this in more detail. Thank you for your help!

Comment: With respect to your assertion that BFPT and $\mathcal T_0$ are equivalent, here's a question for you. Suppose you are given a function $f : D^2 \to D^2$ and you are told that it is a continuous function with respect to the standard topology. Of course, the classical Brouwer fixed point theorem is *true*, so you know that $f$ has a fixed point *somewhere* in $D^2$. But, let's say you don't yet know what that fixed point is. How are you going to define your topology $\mathcal T_0$, and how are you going to apply it to deduce the *existence* of a fixed point of $f$, *without applying the BFPT*?

Comment: @LeeMosher Lee thank you very much for having taken your time to look at this question, and for your great comment. It made me think a lot! I realized that my question was not well framed, in that the function $f$ was actually blurring the picture. With this in mind, I have re-phrased my question, hoping it is more precise now.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366617/brouwers-fixed-point-theorem-and-the-one-point-topology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a way to make this rigorous. To do so, you should keep in mind that your topology $\mathcal T_0$ is not well-defined. Instead it depends on a parameter, namely a choice of a point $p \in D^2$ (what you denoted $x_0$).

To indicate this, let me append $p$ to the definition:
$$\mathcal T_0(p) = \{A \subset X \mid p \in A \quad\text{or}\quad A = \emptyset\}
$$

So with this in mind, perhaps there is an equivalence going on: the Brouwer fixed point theorem is equivalent to the statement that for each function $f : D^2 \to D^2$, if $f$ is continuous in the standard topology then there exists $p \in D^2$ such that $f$ is continuous in the topology $\mathcal T_0(p)$.

Now, I would not say there is anything deep going on here, the topology $\mathcal T_0(p)$ has been concocted to make this equivalence almost trivial.

Comment: thank you very much for a great clarifying answer! May I ask you one question to confirm my understanding, when you say "the standard topology" this is the standard Euclidean topology, is that right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @LeeMosher This is a great answer,it really got me very interested. For the discrete analog of BFPT, Sperner's Lemma, taking your answer as a model, one could say: “Sperner’s Lemma is equivalent to the statement that for each 3-colored triangulation $T$ of a given polygon, if $\partial T$ is odd, then there exists a triangle $\Delta\subset T$ with $\partial \Delta$ odd.” (By odd I mean an odd number of color changes, and by $\partial$ I mean the boundary.) Do you think it can be rigorously expressed in category terms; or even allow for a categorical proof of Brouwer $\Leftrightarrow$ Sperner?

Comment: That's interesting, although I don't know the Sperner approach very well, so I cannot advise you on this.